# How to find installed apt in Ubuntu Mate 16?

Tags: 16.04, apt, ubuntu-mate, synaptic

I installed Alice via Synaptic few days ago using Ubuntu Mate 16.04.06, but I can't find and run it thou... how to run it??

It's not on the Applications drop-down.

I ran it via terminal few days ago it says:

```
user@testbox:~$ alice
No config found, writing a few config to /home/user/.alice/config
Location: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Today I ran it again:

```
user@testbox:~$ alice
Location: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
^C
```

that I gotta ^C it.

The `~/alice/config` file says:

```
{
  'images' => 'show',
  'style' => 'default',
  'address' => '127.0.0.1',
  'debug' => 0,
  'monospace_nicks' => [
    'Shaniqua'
  ],
  'servers' => {},
  'static_prefix' => '/static/',
  'auth' => {},
  'avatars' => 'show',
  'alerts' => 'show',
  'message_store' => 'Memory',
  'port' => '8080',
  'timeformat' => '24',
  'highlights' => [],
  'order' => [],
  'ignore' => [],
  'quitmsg' => 'alice.'
}
```

WTH?? How do I supposed to figure it out ??? I gotta write something a config, or it's already written?

Why does it say 'writing the config' after just I try run Alice and location of my localhost ip address? How weird is that ?? wth man???

Isn't it supposed to be already ready after everything?? I used Ubuntu 10.10 it was pretty great.. Why are newer OS especially Ubuntu aren't any better nowadays, except maybe Lubuntu and XFCE.. Now new default Ubuntu looks like piece of shit cakey flakkey scrambled everything..

How do I supposed to figured it out already?

I am still a pretty newbie in Linux, pretty regular Windows User.

Comment: I suggest that you **[edit]** this to say what you expected when you ran `alice` and what happens when you visit `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` in a web browser while `alice` is running (from the machine it's running on). You ran it twice and it seemed to work both times! The first time, there was no configuration file, so it generated one automatically. ...Or did you intend to install a *different* program called "Alice"? The program you installed has a web-based interface and no other GUI. One shouldn't expect an entry for it in a desktop menu. Right now, I think it's unclear *what* you're asking.

Comment: Your title suggests you're looking for apt. Then you say you can't find alice. You also say you can't figure out how to run it. Then you run it. Then you describe problems with running alice. These are rather contradictory and confusing. I would suggest that you edit your question and make things more clear and focus specifically on the matter at hand. I would especially exclude the superfluous commentary, especially given the use of offensive language.